# Configure neovim to use means other than color for syntax highlighting

Tags: neovim, color

I'm trying to write a `.vimrc` that's portable between `vim` and `nvim` (neovim) and directs the editor to use means other than colors to distinguish syntactic entities.

In `vim`, the following `.vimrc` will direct `vim` to not use any terminal colors, but still distinguish different kinds of syntactic entities like numbers, strings, and comments.

```
syntax on
set t_Co=0
```

Suppose I set my `.config/nvim/init.vim` as the following.

```
source $HOME/.vimrc
```

For whatever reason, `nvim` appears not to honor the `set t_Co=0` setting.

Is there a way to configure neovim to support this? I'm okay with wrapping neovim-specific logic in an `if has('nvim') ... endif` block to get a portable config.

Comment: neovim does not support the `t_xxx` settings

Comment: You might be interested in my https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/d9614c3942a22eb75806bb8e7f8af2a0e24c28dd/links/vim/vimrc#L301-L335

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neovim is a strange beast. It believes it has at least 256 colors available no matter what. But this is not a big deal. Consider the following.

The command `:hi[ghlight]` accepts the following keys:

- `guifg`, `guibg` and `gui` -- colors and attributes for GUI mode (also, for console if `termguicolors` set);
- `ctermfg`, `ctermbg` and `cterm` -- colors and attributes for colored console (`t_Co > 2`);
- `term` -- attributes for monochrome console (`t_Co <= 2`; no colors available, obviously, except for global fore and back);

So to force monochrome mode, no matter what actual underlying terminal is, you only need to set all colors to `NONE` and all of `gui`, `cterm` and `term` to be equal.

An example of such colorscheme:

> ~/.config/nvim/colors/mono.vim

```
hi clear
let g:colors_name = expand('<sfile>:t:r')

let s:colors = #{
    \ Comment: "italic",
    \ Visual: "reverse",
    \ Special: "NONE",
    \ Statement: "NONE",
    \ String: "bold,italic",
    \ Identifier: "NONE",
    "\ more stuff...
    \ }

for [s:group, s:attr] in items(s:colors)
    call printf('hi %s term=%s cterm=%s gui=%s ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE
        \ guifg=NONE guibg=NONE', s:group, s:attr, s:attr, s:attr)->execute()
endfor
```

Still to note that not all terminals provide adequate support for different attributes.